# How to wire a smart thermostat with dual Transformer system? R , Rc, W , Y , G. No C wire. No Jumper

Tags: plumbing, thermostat, installation, nest, wifi

Is this system considered a Dual Transformer system? According to Nest since there is a R and RC cable it must be a dual transformer. But they were unsure and I don't know what that means! I don't have a C wire.  Trying to figure out which smart thermostat is best suited for such a setup and hook it up without tearing up much or pulling new wires!

Hope the picture makes sense. I currently have a Honeywell Thermostat with the following wires hooked up.

R, RC, G, Y , W. **No jumpers**.  I have a FirstCO Air Handler, Burnham Heat, and AC unit outside the house.

- Current Thermostat: Honeywell TH6220D1002
- FirstCo Air Handler: 30MBX-3HW 120V-1PH-60HZ

Google did not help me much with the installation or ideas. They said "learning system may work".

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

[image]

[image: Current System]

[image: Wiring Diagram Air Handler]

[image: wires from Air Handler - three cables boiler, condenser, thermostat]

Comment: Someone has latched onto the "Trying to figure out which smart thermostat to buy" portion to close this as a "purchasing recommendation" which is off-topic. If one were to interpret that as "which _type_" as opposed to "which _brand/model_" it seems to be perfectly reasonable to me. Maybe [edit] your post to remove that sentence and folks will be happy with it.

Comment: How do I open this post again? Or it's up to the mods? @FreeMan

Comment: It's not closed, it just has 1 vote (of 5 required) to do so. Whether closed or open, you just edit to update to meet community standards. In the case (not yet closed), the close vote will expire or the voter may retract it. In case a question is closed, you can still edit it, then it will go into the reopen queue and people will vote to reopen or leave it closed. Take the [tour] and browse through the [help] to see how the system works here.

Comment: Additionally, it would be good to [edit] to include the exact model numbers of all the hardware involved, as well as the make/model of the existing thermostat.

Comment: Done. Added the model numbers and the brand for the thermostat. Couldn't find the model number of the Burnham boiler

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagrams for your boiler and air handler please, as well of photos of the wiring at your air handler for that matter?

Comment: Also, which model of the Nest are you trying to install here?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel thanks. updated it with the diagram and picture of the connections by the airhandler. I ended up buying both last night. Nest E and Nest 2020  hoping one of them will work if not will try the 3rd gen learning thermostat as well. The goal is before pulling apart things figure out which on will work + is the correct one

Comment: @user113807 -- can you get us a closer shot of the cluster of wires shown in your last photo? I can't tell how the air handler hooks into it

Comment: Thanks. Will do. In the mean time thoughts on if it would sense to just run power from a wall adapter? How can that be done. thankds

Comment: @user113807 -- you can't do that for a system that needs to support both heating and A/C

Answer (score 1):

### You have a two-transformer system most likely

From the way your existing thermostat is wired, you most likely indeed have a two-transformer system.  This means that you will need a 3rd gen Nest, since the Nest E dropped two-transformer support, and the 2020 edition Nest supports the same physical connections as the Nest E.